# How to call coroutine from another script? UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the script where the touch action, the main game is on it

```
  var addingGoldPerSec = new GameObject();
    var buttonInstance = addingGoldPerSec.AddComponent<ItemButton>();
    StartCoroutine(buttonInstance.addGoldLoop());
```

And this is the one where I have the coroutine

```
public double goldPerSec
{
    get
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("_goldPerSec"))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        string tmpStartGoldPerSec = PlayerPrefs.GetString("_goldPerSec");
        return double.Parse(tmpStartGoldPerSec);
    }
    set
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("_goldPerSec", value.ToString());
    }
}

public void updateUI()
{
        priceDisplayer.text = LargeNumber.ToString(currentCostPerSec).ToString();
        coinDisplayer.text = "PER SEC\n" + LargeNumber.ToString(goldPerSec).ToString();
        levelDisplayer.text = "LEVEL\n" + level + "/150".ToString();
}
public IEnumerator addGoldLoop()
{
    while (DataController.Instance.gold <= 1e36)
    {
        DataController.Instance.gold += goldPerSec;
        if (Gameplay.Instance.booster == 1)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        }
        else if (Gameplay.Instance.booster == 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a third Script where I manage the data stored into PlayerPrefs

```
 public void loadItemButton(ItemButton itemButton)
{
    itemButton.level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_level",1);
    PlayerPrefs.GetString("_costPerSec", itemButton.currentCostPerSec.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.GetString("_goldPerSec",itemButton.goldPerSec.ToString());
}
public void saveItemButton(ItemButton itemButton)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_level", itemButton.level);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("_costPerSec", itemButton.currentCostPerSec.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("_goldPerSec", itemButton.goldPerSec.ToString());
}
```

I have the second script which is the coroutine one attached into several gameobjects where exists an Upgrade button, per upgrade increases the coin by second you earn, the main problem here is that the coroutine just stops after I touch the screen, so I made another code into the main script so by that way the coroutine will keep working even after touched the screen, so I made a script where is the GameObject, but it just throws me NullReferenceException, tried a check with TryCatch and throws me that the problem is coming from the GameObject that I have created on the main script, but if is that way I need to attach to the main object where the main script exists, like more than 10 gameobjects where the coroutine exists, I think Singleton is not the way, it deletes me all the information above there by instantiating on Awake, I never thought about making static so I did as you told me and I need to change almost of my code, every text is attached into each gameobjects, to make a non-static member work with a static-member need to delete Monobehaviour but it just makes the game explode, thanks for helping me.

Comment: Scripts are linked to a gameobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two scripts and attach them, for example, at Main Camera. The first script contains your timer with all variables:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class TimerToCall : MonoBehaviour {
 //Create your variable
 ...
 //Your function timer
 public IEnumerator Counter() {
  ...
 }
}
```

In the second script, you will call the timer:

```
public class callingTimer : MonoBehaviour {
 void Start() {
  //TimerToCall script linked to Main Camera, so
  StartCoroutine(Camera.main.GetComponent<TimerToCall>().Counter());
 }
}
```

---

if you want to have for example the second script not linked to any gameObjet you could use static property:

in first script linked:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(CallingTimer.ExampleCoroutine());   
}
```

in second script not linked, you use the static property:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CallingTimer
{
    public static IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine()
    {
        //Print the time of when the function is first called.
        Debug.Log("Started Coroutine at timestamp : " + Time.time);

        //yield on a new YieldInstruction that waits for 5 seconds.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        //After we have waited 5 seconds print the time again.
        Debug.Log("Finished Coroutine at timestamp : " + Time.time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello I am using the script as Singleton and using in 12 upgrade buttons, can't attach it to a single camera because I need to attach it on 12 upgrade buttons.

Comment: i have added a second solution if yo dont want to have a script linked..

Comment: thank for you help, but I am having an issue with Monobehaviour and static members, could you help me please? Just eddited it right now.

Comment: its difficult to undesrtand what you want..your explanations are confused for me...could you reformulate your question and show completely the scripts : the caller which calls the coroutine and the coroutine.. because you mix plenty of objects...i need to shwo how you have defined all variables

Comment: Ok Frenchy already made an update with it, thanks for helping me, trying by different ways for lot of days and nothing, no more ideas coming up since I am beginner with Unity, I will be very appreciated with your help, thanks for taking your time.

Comment: the script with coroutine is attached to lot of GameObject?

Comment: if you have the possibility to put your unity project on github or another shared drive, it will be easier for me to see...

Comment: sorry if my explanation was wrong, so the script where is the coroutine is attached into several Gameobjects to use the classes that are there and not the coroutine itself

Comment: One question again: ItemButton is the script which contains the Coroutine? and it is "buttonInstance" which is null reference?

Comment: Hello Frenchy, that's correct, sorry if I am responding now, having hard days dealing with it, and still not good...

Comment: i dont reproduce the error...so i need to have the complete project if you want help

Comment: Hello Frenchy, long time not talking about, just wanted to give you my thanks for helping me, I just solved it with static, adding with += a non-static member on a Singleton member which is static, so with Static Ienumerator,  DataController.Instance.goldPerSecond += goldPerSec; and DataController.Instance.gold += DataController.Instance.goldPerSecond;